# hibernate creating another unnecessary index on a relationship table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a relationship like this: A room has many users and a user belongs to many rooms. I don't really need the connection between users -> rooms, so I removed and hibernate created a relationship table called `room_users` which is fine.
But also, created these two indexes:

[image]

as you can imagine, the `uk_rdxxx` index is wrong and is not allowing me to save more than one user per room. and I have no idea where that came from. here is my class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rooms", indexes = {
    @Index(columnList = "uid", unique = true),
    @Index(columnList = "fullName", name = "full_name_idx")
})
@JsonInclude(content = Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, of = {"uid"})
@ToString(of = {"name", "uid", "fullName"})
@NamedEntityGraphs(
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "with-messages",
        attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("messages")}))
public class Room extends AbstractAggregateRoot implements Serializable {

  @OneToMany(targetEntity = User.class, cascade = {})
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: You describe a many-to-many relationship, but you've annotated the corresponding entity field with `@OneToMany`.  Use `@ManyToMany`.  Also use `@ManyToMany` on the other side if the relationship is navigable from that direction.

Comment: you were right. I thought that since I don't have the connection between User and Room anymore I could annotate with @OneToMany but I can't

Comment: Whether it is navigable in both directions is a completely separate consideration from the multiplicity of the relationship.  Always describe your data accurately if you want Hibernate or any other automated mechanism to generate appropriate structures (and commands) for it.